# Does there exist a countable proper subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \setminus S$ is infinite but not dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does there exist a countable proper subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathbb{Q} \setminus S$ is infinite but **not** dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: All subsets of $\mathbb Q$ are countable. Take your favourite infinite subset which is not dense in $\mathbb R$ e.g. $\mathbb Z$ is nowhere dense, and take the complement for $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb Q:x>0\}$ is a countable proper subset of $\mathbb Q$ and it is such that $\mathbb Q\setminus S$ is infinite but not dense in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Oh thank you! :) I am really not clear-headed now.